# Does the Peer Pressure badge apply to answers as well as questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, peer-pressure-badge

I gave a dumb answer to a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112489). It earned a sum of -3 on my answer, and I was resigned to scurry away from the question and hide in the corner to lick my wounds. The displayed sum was minus 3.

I clicked 'Delete' on my answer (24+ hours ago), and the answer has appeared to have removed itself. I can see it shaded pinkish with the 'Undelete' option.

The badge hasn't been awarded. I am only wondering about the frequency of the badge calculations and handouts.

**Questions**: Does the Peer Pressure badge apply to answers as well as questions?

If I suspect that a badge hasn't been awarded (in error), is it appropriate to send an email to the SO team?

Comment: I was awarded the Peer Pressure badge for deleting a -3 net vote answer - so yes it does apply. My original answer was a bit crock - which is why it was down-voted I assume - but I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

The Peer Pressure badge does apply to answers as well as questions.

However, you'll only get it if the displayed score on your post is at least -3. i.e the number of down-votes exceeds the number of up-votes by 3 or more.

Comment: It would have been easier to say "Your displayed score must be at least -3"

Comment: But then there wouldn't be a chart!

Comment: @Pesto - I removed the chart as someone clearly didn't like it (other than TheTXI I think).

Answer (score 2):

Who knows how long this has been on, but it looks like you get another kind of hint, (if rep and votes weren't dimming enough) on eligibility for a Peer Pressure badge.

When you get -3 or more, it looks as if the text colour of the post will dim a shade:

[image: dim bulb]

Comment: been this way for a long long time. I guess that's a good sign, it means you're rarely seeing posts that negatively voted! Also: in unrelated news, the non-aliased fonts in your screenshot make my eyes bleed.

Comment: Bleeding means the fonts are nice and sharp.